# Tyring to set up modelview with Flask-Admin causes ImportError

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I am trying to add a User model view to Flask-Admin.  However, I get `ImportError: cannot import name db`.  Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

`app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import flask_admin as admin
from app.models import User

db = SQLAlchemy()
admin = admin.Admin(name="Admin Panel")

def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    db.init_app(app)
    admin.init_app(app)
    admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
    return app
```

`app/models.py`:

```
from . import db, login_manager

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

When I add `admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))`, I have to add `from app.models import User` as well.  I get this error after adding these lines:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 3, in <module>
        from app.models import User, Role
      File "/home/qadim/PycharmProjects/esouq/app/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from app.models import User
      File "/home/qadim/PycharmProjects/esouq/app/models.py", line 9, in <module>
        from . import db, login_manager
    ImportError: cannot import name db
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has the line `from app.models import User` in `__init__.py`.  The problem is that `app.models` has `from . import db`.  This is a circular import: `__init__` tries to import `User`, which tries to import `db`, which isn't defined until after `__init__` tries to import `User`.  To solve this, move your local app imports below the definitions of all the global extension stuff.

Currently, your code looks something like:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app.models import User

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

You need to change it to:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

from app.models import User
```